# PowerShell split string using RegEx

Tags: regex, powershell

Could you please help me!?

This is what I'm trying to achieve with **PowerShell** - export emails to CSV file from particular mailbox with needed data (Subject, FromDisplayName, SubmittedDateTime, MessageTrackingReportId). So I made it using following four strings:

```
$msg = Search-MessageTrackingReport -Identity MyMailBox -BypassDelegateChecking

#get relevant info from that mailbox and save it to CSV file
$msg | %{ Get-MessageTrackingReport -Identity $_.MessageTrackingReportId -BypassDelegateChecking } | Select Subject, FromDisplayName, SubmittedDateTime, MessageTrackingReportId | Export-CSV C:\MyFile.csv -NoTypeInformation

#import CSV file and get rid of dublicates and select only needed columns
$temp = Import-CSV C:\MyFile.csv | sort MessageTrackingReportId -Unique | Select Subject, FromDisplayName, SubmittedDateTime

#export CSV file
$file = $temp | Export-CSV C:\MyFile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

But the problem I'm facing is that Subject of email may look like this:

```
** FAN-CRITICAL Service Alert: LTC-SW-NEX01/fan-status is OK ** (24x7 OOH Alerts)
```

or

```
** SM-CRITICAL Service Alert: PRDDC1FAS001/snapmirror-lagtime is CRITICAL ** (24x7 OOH Alerts)
```

or

```
** RECOVERY Service Alert: PRDDC1ADS001/CPU Load is WARNING ** (24x7 OOH Alerts)
```

or

```
... (Something in similar format)
```

So I need to split this string and replace Subject column with those four new columns in my CSV file:

1. AlertType which is - `FAN-CRITICAL Service Alert` or `SM-CRITICAL Service Alert` or `RECOVERY Service Alert` or `...`
2. MachineName which is - `LTC-SW-NEX01` or `PRDDC1FAS001` or `PRDDC1ADS001` or `...`
3. AlertName which is - `fan-status` or `snapmirror-lagtime` or `CPU Load` or `...`
4. Status which is - `OK` or `CRITICAL` or `WARNING` or `...`

So in the end of the day my CSV file should have these following columns:

- AlertType
- MachineName
- AlertName
- Status
- FromDisplayName
- SubmittedDateTime
- MessageTrackingReportId

I know that I need to use **RegEx** but I don't have any experience working with it, so could anyone please help me, how can I combine **PowerShell** and **RegEx** to achieve my goals.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a viable long-term solution. While this will work for now, you really ought to have your monitoring system recording to individual fields in a database so that this data is more easily stored, retrieved & reported on.

Comment: I know, I import CSV file to DB afterwards!

Comment: No, I'm saying eliminate the email processing altogether and record directly to a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to start with:

```
$messages = @(
    "** FAN-CRITICAL Service Alert: LTC-SW-NEX01/fan-status is OK ** (24x7 OOH Alerts)",
    "** SM-CRITICAL Service Alert: PRDDC1FAS001/snapmirror-lagtime is CRITICAL ** (24x7 OOH Alerts)",
    "** RECOVERY Service Alert: PRDDC1ADS001/CPU Load is WARNING ** (24x7 OOH Alerts)"
)


$messages | %{

    $_ -match "/*/*\s*(?<AlertType>[\w ]+?):\s*(?<MachineName>[^\/]+)\/(?<AlertName>.*?)\s\w+\s(?<Status>\w+)\s\*\*"  | Out-Null  

    $matches["AlertType"]
    $matches["MachineName"]
    $matches["AlertName"]
    $matches["Status"]
}
```

More explanations on regex and capture groups with powershell [here](http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/Powershell_regular_expressions).

Answer (score 0):

```
([\w ]+?):\s*([^\/]+)\/(.*?)\s\w+\s(\w+)\s\*\*
```

You can try this.See demo.Grab the capture.

https://regex101.com/r/iY3eK8/9

Comment: Nice one, thanx but how to combine it with PowerShell in my case?

Comment: @user4340729 havent used Powershell :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$regex = '\*\* (.+?) Service Alert: (.+?)/(.+?) is (.+?) \*\*'

if ($text -match $regex)
  {
   $AlertName,$MachineName,$AlertType,$Status = $Matches[1..4]
  }
```